# Displaying a list with numerous values

Tags: php, mysql

I was hoping somebody may be able to help with my problem.

I am using the following query

```
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT p.pattern_for,
c_main.name AS cat_name, c_main.slug AS cat_slug,
c_sub.name AS sub_cat_name, c_sub.slug AS sub_cat_slug
FROM products AS p
INNER JOIN categories AS c_main ON c_main.name = p.c_main
INNER JOIN categories AS c_sub ON c_sub.name = p.c_sub
WHERE p.stock_level > 0 AND p.pattern_for != ''
GROUP BY p.pattern_for
ORDER BY p.pattern_for ASC");
$query->execute();
```

The above works fine however I want to give the person creating the products the ability to be able to add numerous values to the column 'pattern_for'.

So it could have the following values -

```
Product A - 'Men, Women, Children
Product B - 'Women'
Product C - 'Toddlers, Girls'
Product D - 'Men, Boys'
Product E - 'Girls, Women, Babies'
```

What I need it to do is (in the query) split the values using the comma and then display them all in a list but also grouping them so it only shows once and also ordering alphabetically.

So for example the output of the above would be...

```
Babies
Boys
Children
Girls
Men
Toddlers
Women
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Please show tangible efforts of solving this on your own, and if you run into issues, report back, and we can guide you in the right direction. Take a read of [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Hi Marcus, thanks for your reply. I have tried the following - SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(p.pattern_for, ', ', 1), ', ', -1) AS pattern_for,   and then grouping by the alias pattern_for and this gets the first value fine however I am unsure how to do it for the second without repeating it like SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(p.pattern_for, ', ', 2), ', ', -1) AS pattern_for2, but I want all the results to be under the alias pattern_for so that I can group by them. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Post the above comment as part of your question on a section entitled as: `This is what I've tried so far`

Answer (score 0):

For those who may come across this problem in the future here is the query I ended up using...

```
$query_pattern_for = $db->prepare("SELECT p.pattern_for,
    c_main.name AS cat_name, c_main.slug AS cat_slug,
    c_sub.name AS sub_cat_name, c_sub.slug AS sub_cat_slug
    FROM products AS p
    INNER JOIN categories AS c_main ON c_main.name = p.c_main
    INNER JOIN categories AS c_sub ON c_sub.name = p.c_sub
    WHERE c_main.type = 0 AND c_sub.type = 0 AND p.stock_level = 0 AND p.reorder = 0 AND p.pattern_for != '' AND p.status = 1
    OR c_main.type = 0 AND c_sub.type = 0 AND p.stock_level > 0 AND p.pattern_for != '' AND p.status = 1
    GROUP BY pattern_for
    ORDER BY p.pattern_for ASC");
    $query_pattern_for->execute();
    $count_pattern_for = $query_pattern_for->rowCount();
```

and then the php...

```
while ($row = $query_pattern_for->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

                    $get_pattern_for .= $row['pattern_for'] . ',';

                }

                $get_pattern_for = str_replace(', ', ',', $get_pattern_for);

                $get_pattern_for = explode(",", $get_pattern_for);

                $get_pattern_for = array_unique($get_pattern_for);
                $get_pattern_for = array_filter($get_pattern_for);
                sort($get_pattern_for);

                foreach($get_pattern_for as $pattern_for) {

                    $pattern_for_slug = str_replace(' ','',$pattern_for);
                    $pattern_for_slug = str_replace('/','-',$pattern_for_slug);
                    $pattern_for_slug = preg_replace('/[^\w-]/', '', $pattern_for_slug);
                    $pattern_for_slug = strtolower($pattern_for_slug);

                    echo '<a href="'.$url.'&patterns-for='.$pattern_for_slug.'"><li>'; if ($get_patterns_for == $pattern_for_slug) { echo '<div class="tick-box-selected">&#10004;</div>'.$pattern_for.''; } else { echo '<div class="tick-box"></div>'.$pattern_for.''; } echo '</li></a>';

                }
```

I hope this helps somebody out someday.

Thank you
Dan